# Resubmit app with old app id

Tags: ios

I have got some error when try to submit app to iTunes Connect: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html

The situation is as follows:

1. I create an app (device family iPad/iPhone) and submit it.
2. I have changed device family to iPhone only and try to submit and got error.

I want to delete old app which have device family iPad/iPhone and submit the new which have device family iPhone only. Can users get a notification from App Store about the update or they should to remove app and download it again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your app as a new app if you want to reduce the number of supported device.

One solution to notify your current user is to submit an update of your previous universal app  with the previous code running on both devices and add a short notice somewhere on the start screen with a link to you new application. You could also show this notice only for iPhone user only using

```
  if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ){
displayNewAppLink /* Device is iPhone */}
```

The problem would be if your app is not free and you want previous user to get free update. This is not possible submitting a new application.